# Angular passing the expression to style

Tags: angular

I have a problem on how to pass an expression to angular style and this is what i have:

```
color = '#';
letters = ['000000','FF0000','00FF00','0000FF','FFFF00','00FFFF','FF00FF','C0C0C0'];

this.color += this.letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.letters.length)];
```

HTML:

```
[style.background-color]="'expression'"
```

I want to get random color from letters and set it as background. console.log(this.color); returns me one of colors from letters but i can't figure how to use expression in html.

Thaks for reading and help!

Comment: remove the inner ' and leave it just like [style.background-color]="expression"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use it like :**

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': color}"
// or
[style.background-color]="color"
```

---

> Or you can just create a function and use it like , this will generate
>   random colour each time it called

**Component Side :**

```
getColor(){
    return `#${this.letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.letters.length)]}`;
}
```

**Template Side :**

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': getColor()}"
// or
[style.background-color]="getColor()"
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-random-bg)** (Hit refresh to get random colours each time)

Comment: @Bognar , Glad to know , Happy Coding BTW :)